# Calculating distribution minimum and maximum values from known p5/mode/p95 values

Tags: distributions, matlab, monte-carlo, quantiles

I am defining triangular and Beta-Pert distributions in MATLAB to produce random samples for Monte Carlo analysis. This is a trivial task if the minimum, maximum and mode are known using:

makedist('Triangular', 'a','b','c'); [where a,b,c are min/mode/max values]
makedist('Beta','a','b'); [where a and b can be calculated from min/mode/max using the Beta-Pert relations]

However, my users will provide the mode and percentile values (P5/P95, P10/P90 etc.) and the distribution type. As far as I can tell MATLAB can only accept distributions defined using their minimum, mode and maximum values.

So my question is how do I derive the minimum and maximum values of a triangular or Pert distribution given the mode and low/high percentile values?

http://www.greatsolutions.com.br/images/BetaEng.pdf shows a method for doing it empirically but Palisade @Risk has an analytical solution which I'm looking to replicate.

It can't be as simple as using the inverse cumulative distribution function equation as I think there would be too many unknowns to  solve it.

I would greatly appreciate any help on this because this level of statistical detail is a bit over my head and the link above is the closest thing I can find online to the solution I am after.

Comment: @eriksv88, A triangular distribution has the parameters $a,b,c$ which are min, max and mode. So if you have the 5th and 95th percentiles and the mode, then you are finding values for two unknowns (max and min) satisfying two equations (for the 5th and 9th percentiles). Why would there be too many unknowns?

Comment: I think Matt F. is right, the problem ils well defined as you have as many unknown (3) as parameters (3). Do you really need analytical expression though? For the  triangular distribution, I think it's feasible but I'm not so sure for the Beta-Pert one.. Could a numerical solution do the trick?